# Streaming a large CSV file into a mongoDB database using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, filestream

Searching for an efficient and quick way to stream a large (10 million lines) of csv data into a mongoose database.

Problems that arise are dealing with streaming instead of importing which could be solve with fs.createReadStream (although still learning how to use it) and how to deal with inserting that large amount of data into the mongoDB using mongoose because overloading mongoose/mongo with insert requests could lead to some errors.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

you simply need 'stream-to-mongo-db' and 'csvtojson' npm library.
here is the example code i use to dump millions of records from BIG csv files. It just works!

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csvtojson');
const streamToMongoDB = require('stream-to-mongo-db').streamToMongoDB;

const csvFile = './bigFiles.csv';
const dbURL = 'mongodb://localhost/tweets';
const collection = 'tweets';

fs.createReadStream(csvFile)
  .pipe(csv())
  .pipe(streamToMongoDB({ 
   dbURL : dbURL, collection : collection
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a insertMany() method in mongoose. but that only lets you insert 10 000 docs only per once so.. My solution is to you loop asyncly using that method and insert untll the stream finishes..